# Is it possible to build a CPU from content-addressable memory?

Tags: design, microprocessor, cpu, chip-design

Every modern programming language use objects and not C/C++ style struct/class.
In C/C++ every data member has a size, so addressing a struct member is basically a memory address + offset. But script languages just like JavaScript and many others use an object ID that contains key/value pairs. These key/value pairs can be also an object ID.

So nowadays hardware memory is addressed with memory address + offset or memory address to a lookup table where key/value are stored.

A memory address can contains data or ASM code that is executable by a CPU.

So is it possible to build a hardware that only contains content-addressable memory (CAM)?

I can imagine the following:

Data:

```
id: 23
  -key: 123, value: 7
  -key: 456, value: 8
  -key: 789, value: 0
```

This is a scheme of a content addressable memory block. This block can be write with a SetValue(id, key, value) opcode and can read with a GetValue(id, key)

My idea is that if I specify a key/value pair for executable memory block I got a CPU.

If a memory block contains special key value pairs it will act like an opcode. For example if contains a key that is < 100 than it is an opcode

```
id: 45
  -key: 12, value: 7  // key 12 opcode for add two data
  -key: 10, value: 8  // key 10 is arg1, value is a data
  -key: 11, value: 9  // key 11 is arg2, value is a data
```

In this architecture every memory block an object and every memory block a minimal CPU at the same time. Do you think is it possible to build such a hardware?

Comment: My gut feeling is that you can use CAM to implement conventional memory, hence everything that can be done with conventional memory can be done with CAM. With a 'little' help of the CPU the reverse is true too. (Which is not unexpected, since all 'real' computers we know are computationally equivalent.)

Comment: Yu can probably build a Turing machine using a CAM. And you can notionally do anything computationally doable with a Turing machine. BUT, then you'd have to use it. The chance of it being a worthwhile exercise in other than an academic ense seems low.

Comment: Wait, C++ doesn't have objects? I'm pretty sure an instance of a C++ class is an object.

Comment: Yes, C++ has objects but object members are addressable with an offset not a content. obj1.member1 means get address of "obj1" and calculate offset of "member1". In JavaScript obj1.member1 means get the object called "obj1" and lookup for member "member1" in "obj1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building and using large content-addressable memories is expensive and difficult.  The most common design for a CAM is to have a number of addressable memory cells that compare their contents to a matched value that is passed in, and if they match they trigger a set of associated cells to produce output on a shared bus.  This means two things:

- As well as the value to output, we need memory cells for the addressable content, and additional logic to perform the comparison between that content and the value being searched for.  Also, because there is no single predetermined location each value can be stored in, some mechanism of allocating space for new entries to be added is required[1].  Taken together, these make the size of a CAM much larger than the size of a traditional memory that stores the same amount of data.
- Because the units output to a shared bus, they *must* be arranged so that only one at a time can match.  This means that before an item can be added to a CAM the CAM must first be searched to ensure that it won't conflict with existing entries.  If there is a conflict, the existing entry must be deleted before the new entry can be added.  If the data is required to persist indefinitely (i.e. the CAM isn't being used as a cache, as most current applications of CAMs in processors are) then this means the addressable content must always be unique -- this requirement usually means that the size of addressable content needs to be quite large, further adding to the cost of implementation.

There is also a development process reason why architectures that work like this are likely to remain rare for the foreseeable future: a large proportion of CPU development work these days is performed using FPGAs to run the processor being designed.  FPGAs do not usually have the kind of shared bus arrangement that CAMs are implemented with -- to select among multiple possible source values, an FPGA uses multiplexers instead, but large trees of multiplexers are slower than such a shared bus, so large CAMs in FPGAs are not usually very fast, making developing architectures that use them particularly difficult.

For these reasons, while it is possible to use CAMs to accelerate applications that use small amounts of memory, building an entire modern general purpose computer using them for all storage seems to be unjustifiably tricky.

[1] - this can be mitigated a little by the use of set-associative CAMs, but that's only really useful for caches as it makes it more likely for conflicts to arise that require an element to be deleted from the memory when it is still needed, which is an acceptable tradeoff for a cache but not for the kind of use proposed here.

Comment: I'm not comfortable enough with the facts here to make this part of the answer, but I'll leave it as a comment: I'd guess that for a system like the one described in the question you'd want at least a 48-bit tag on each item (32 bits for an object ID and 16 bits for a unique hash code for the entry) attached to a 32-bit data value.  CAMs usually use static RAM (I don't know if they can be made to work with dynamic RAM, you'd certainly need a different way of refreshing them than the traditional approach) and the matcher adds one XOR and one input to an AND gate per bit, so would usually be ...

Comment: ... 16 transistors per addressable bit and 6 transistors per content bit, giving 30 transistors per bit of actual stored data, versus typical dynamic RAM which requires only 1 transistor and 1 capacitor per bit, meaning that a system using CAM in this manner will likely cost at least 15 times as much as a system using DRAM for it. The CAM will respond faster than DRAM -- but using CAM doesn't give any kind of locality of reference so caching it would be useless, meaning that the faster response time would be necessary in any case, thus comparing static CAM against DRAM seems to be reasonable.

Comment: Thx for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

You certainly *can* build one of these, and Wikipedia claims that [the Goodyear MPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodyear_MPP) was such a thing. It isn't quite, but it has most of the real elements that you'd actually want.

Putting the code in CAM as well offers you a lot of inconvenience for no real benefit, so you'd store it in regular DRAM. For practical purposes, you would have a CAM *peripheral*, like a graphics accelerator. And you wouldn't use it to run regular Javascript; the speed advantage for selecting one out of a few dozen object members would be tiny. It makes sense if you want to ask the question "which of these million items have value X"?

Answer (score 4):

Practically all modern CPUs do, in fact, contain content-addressable memory.  However, they use it only in very specialised areas where its unique advantages make sense, and where its relatively high cost can be tolerated.

The question that a standard memory answers is: **knowing the address of a storage location, what data is stored there?**

The question that a content-addressable memory answers is: **knowing the data stored somewhere in memory, what address (if any) refers to it?**

The latter is useful in data caches and branch predictors, when you want to know whether any of the (perhaps 16) ways in a particular cache set is assigned to a particular address; in this case the address is the data stored in the CAM, aka "tag RAM" in the old days.  The actual data stored in the cache is in normal SRAM.